# EOL while scanning string literal, Unknown Emoji

Tags: discord, discord.py

Command raised an exception: HTTP Exception: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji and EOL while scanning string literal are the 2 errors I have having while trying to add a reaction to an embed msg with python (discord.py)

Here is the full code, the problem is around the exclamation mark

```py
@client.command()
async def ask(ctx, *, question=None):
    try:
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(f'http://askdiscord.netlify.app/b/{ctx.message.author.id}.txt')
        if page.read():
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFF5555, title="Error", description="You are banned from using AskDiscord!")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, content=None)
            return
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        pass
    if question:
        channel = client.get_channel(780111762418565121)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x7289DA, title=question, description=f"""
Question asked by {ctx.message.author} ({ctx.message.author.id}). If you think this question violates our rules, click ❗️ below this message to report it
""")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.author.id}")
        message = await channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
        for emoji in ('❗️'):
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        for emoji in (''):
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x55FF55, title="Question asked", description="Your question has been send! You can view in the answer channel in the [AskDiscord server](https://discord.gg/KwUmPHKmwq)")
        await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", description=f"Please make sure you ask a question...", color=0xFF5555)
        await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

Comment: @Łukasz Kwieciński That does not help sadly

Comment: What happens when you do `await message.add_reaction('❗️')` outside the loop?

Comment: Any reason why you're using a tuple and a for loop? Try replacing `('❗️')` with `['❗️']`.

Answer (score 0):

Tuple need to have a `,` at the end if there is only one element in it else its considered as a string in your case change `('❗️')` to `('❗️',)`